# removeClass function on complete fired multiple times

Tags: jquery

I want to change a class of li-elements inside a ul list.

For that I use a .remove with a function on complete state.

In my case the part of the function fired for every element which is successfully changed. Not only at the end of changing all elements.

Is there a way to fire only the function on totally complete of all matches?

```
<ul class="ul_A">
<li class="test">A</li>
<li class="test">B</li>
<li class="test">C</li>
<li class="test">D</li>
<li class="test">E</li>
<li>
  <ul class="ul_B">
    <li class="test">A</li>
    <li class="test">B</li>
    <li class="test">C</li>
    <li class="test">D</li>
    <li class="test">E</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<button id="go">
click to test
</button>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '#go', function() {
    //console.log('lets go');
    var myelementA = $('.ul_A li');
    var myelementB = $('.ul_B li');
    //console.log(myelementA,myelementB);
    $(myelementA, myelementB).removeClass('test', '300', 'swing', function() {
      console.log('here we go');
      alert("now class is removed!");
    });
  });

});
```

I tried to make a fiddle but on top something is wrong with it, it won't work
https://jsfiddle.net/05ncthwj/3/

Comment: Please see: https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/ RemoveClass only accepts Class Names or a Function. If you want to use Easing, you have to add the jQuery UI library.

Comment: is there a way to do it without UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per jQuery UI:

> Similar to native CSS transitions, jQuery UI's class animations provide a smooth transition from one state to another while allowing you to keep all the details about which styles to change in CSS and out of your JavaScript. All class animation methods, including `.removeClass()`, support custom durations and easings, as well as provide a callback for when the animation completes.

Regarding the callback function:

> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

So if you want 1 alert, you have to make sure it's done at the end of the "loop".

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/prnvy504/15/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#go', function() {
    //console.log('lets go');
    var c = $("li.test").length;
    var i = 0;
    $("li.test").removeClass('test', 300, function() {
      console.log(++i, c);
      if (i == c) {
        alert("Remove Complete");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/removeClass/

Comment: is there a way to do it without UI?

Comment: @relo80 that depends on what you want to accomplish. What is the highest priority? Animation? Triggering callback after it's done? Or timing?

Comment: @relo80 consider using Animate: https://api.jquery.com/animate You can change the style of the element and then remove the class at the end in the callback.